# Change format for data imported from file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

My data file is Tab separated and looks like this:

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
... ... ..  .........
```

I imported them in Python using `numpy`, here is my script:

```
from numpy import loadtxt

np_data = loadtxt('u.data', delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
print(np_data)
```

I just want to print it to see the result, but it gives me different a format:

```
[[  1.96000000e+02   2.42000000e+02   3.00000000e+00   8.81250949e+08]
 [  1.86000000e+02   3.02000000e+02   3.00000000e+00   8.91717742e+08]
 [  2.20000000e+01   3.77000000e+02   1.00000000e+00   8.78887116e+08]
 ...,
 [  2.76000000e+02   1.09000000e+03   1.00000000e+00   8.74795795e+08]
 [  1.30000000e+01   2.25000000e+02   2.00000000e+00   8.82399156e+08]
 [  1.20000000e+01   2.03000000e+02   3.00000000e+00   8.79959583e+08]]
```

There is point `.` in every number in `print(np_data)`. How to format them to look like my original data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this, turn out I miss the `dtype` argument , so the script should look like this:

```
from numpy import loadtxt

np_data = loadtxt('u.data',dtype=int ,delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
print(np_data)
```

and done

Comment: Although this looks like the .data file, the important question is whether you want to do integer arithmetic (which may be less accurate) in numpy. How it happens to look on screen isn't the primary concern.

Comment: actually I just want to do some integer arithmetic, it maybe result in float number.